# GraphQL input type not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, schema, apollo-server

I have a backend made with Express / Apollo Server / GraphQL / MongoDB / Mongoose and a frontend made with React.

I have my component where I want to do mutations and queries, I checked the connection between frontend and backend and it's good.

My mutation on backend:

`createUser(input: SignupInput!): AuthUser!`

```
input SignupInput {
    name: String!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
  }
```

The AuthUser return is an User! that has more fields but I think it's not necessary info.

On my frontend

```
const NEW_USER = gql`
  mutation CreateUser($type: SignupInput!) {
    createUser(input: $type) {
      user {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

```
const [newTest, { data }] = useMutation(NEW_USER);
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    newTest({
      variables: {
        name: formData.name,
        username: formData.username,
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password,
      },
    });
  };
```

The network response for error 400:

```
"Variable \"$type\" of required type \"SignupInput!\" was not provided."
```

I don't really understand why this is happening, I've seen in other people's code that creating the variable with the name of the input type you have on the backend works.

If I try to destructure the SignInput! type and write {$name: !String, ...) I get this error:

```
Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"Mutation.createUser\".", locations: […], extensions: {…} }
```

Comment: newTest({
      variables: { 
       >>>>>  type: { <<<<<<<<
        name:

Comment: Thanks bud, really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newTest({
      variables: {
        input: {
        name: formData.name,
        username: formData.username,
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password,
       }
      },
    });
```

Input was not passed in the mutation function.